# YouTube HTML5 Player - Can somebody explain it to me?

Tags: html5

HOW are the videos rendered on our website using only html5 without any `<video>` tags on the website? How do they control the play? AJAX? How is the video streamed? Which tehique? HOW does the video get to our website?

Where is the video rendered? Server? Client? Is it sent frame-by-frame?

Comment: There is a <video> tag. They are rendered the same way all video is via a codec ( simply said ) the problem with html5 video is that all browsers support different 'codec ' / file format/ video encapsulation. The idea is basically to extend the HTMLMediaElement so you can control it via JS. It is streamed usually by CDN like normal video is, simply the browser have native implementation of the 'codec' used. It is rendered client side. Is is being send in in different ways RTP, Unicast, Multicast, p2p .. etc.. those are protocols developed for that purpose and were available before html5 video.

Comment: There are about 6 questions in there, so do a little research and pare it down a bit. start here: http://www.w3schools.com/HTML/html5_video.asp . I'm almost certian they are using a video tag, but its probably injected via script, not raw markup.

Answer (score 1):

The embed code from YouTube contains an [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) tag which is like a web page within a web page. The iframe projects a dynamic page from the YouTube site on to your site.

This dynamic page contains the `<video>` tag.

Below is the embed code for Nyan Cat:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QH2-TGUlwu4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

If you open the page listed in the `src` attribute and search the HTML markup in the browser developer tools there is a `<video>` within the first few `<div>` tags.

```
<video class="video-stream html5-main-video" style="width: 670px; height: 317px; left: 0px; top: -317px; transform: none;" tabindex="-1"></video>
```